# How to catch an exception in TValueListEditor that occurs when keyUnique is set to True?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Need to prevent duplicate keys in TValueListEditor but exception generated by this component does not have unique class so I can not seprate it from any other exception that may occur in program which makes existence of keyUnique kind of useless. I have tried capturing it at global level:

```
public
  { Public declarations }
  procedure MyExcept(Sender : TObject; E : Exception );

procedure TForm2.MyExcept(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
  showmessage(E.Message);
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnException := MyExcept;
end;
```

PS

VCL removes duplicates by itself (if keyUnique is True) so absense of unique class for this exception is bad but not as bad as I was thinking. Also program does not fail with exception because looks like VCL catches it internally & simply displays explanatory message so user can continue with the program.

Comment: Thanks to clumsy design of `TValueListEditor` your chances are pretty slim. It doesn't provide any event for key conflict and the method `TValueListStrings.KeyIsValid` is not virtual, so that you can't override it. You also can't control instantiation of `TValueListEditor.FStrings`. I can only see hacky/ugly solutions to your problem by hooking into `TValueListStrings.KeyIsValid` or checking whether exception message conforms to format `SKeyConflict` declared in `Vcl.Consts`.

Comment: I don't have any Delphi installed to test, but you can consider using [`OnValidate`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.ValEdit.TValueListEditor.OnValidate) event handler to manually check for duplicates and to raise whatever exception you want (or perform other actions).

Comment: @OldSkull `OnValidate` is only invoked by changes made from user interface while `KeyIsValid` is invoked also by changes to items from the code.

Comment: Tried without debugger (Shift + Ctrl + F9 in Delphi XE2) & looks like VCL manages this internally because program does not fail with scary looking message but instead window with corresponding message appears which user can close & continue working with the program.